Get DynamoDB item as Document in .Net failed with : `Specified cast is not valid. at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.DynamoDBEntry.AsString()`
I'm trying to get items from aws DynamoDb using the following code:
var request = new GetItemRequest()
{
    TableName = AccountsTable,
    Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
    {
        { "CustomerName", new AttributeValue() { S = "John" } },
        { "CustomerType", new AttributeValue() { S = CustomerType.ToString() } }, // An enum passed to the method
    }
};
var response = await dynamoDbClient.GetItemAsync(request, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
foreach (var kvp in response.Item)
{
    Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(kvp)); // Item successfully selected and logged, and I can see the Item values in cloudWatch. 
}

if (response.Item.Count == 0) return null;
var itemAsDocument = Document.FromAttributeMap(response.Item); // exception raised.

when I run this code in AWS lambda function, the logs shows the item have been selected and it's values logged.
but once it reaches the line:
 var itemAsDocument = Document.FromAttributeMap(response.Item);

the logs shows the following exception:
fail    System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.DynamoDBEntry.AsString()

how to solve this?
